# Querying on Firebase or on the client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically I have a set a of data on my website and on I have some checkboxes where the user can check to filter the data. The data will be 40 items per page. Should I query my data in firebase or when I get the data back from firebase. The reason I'm asking is because the user can check and uncheck the checkboxes which means every time the users the users does that I'm getting charged, since firebase charges by use by at the end I want to make sure I follow the best practices.

The queries will have `OR`. I know in firebase there's not such a thing as an `OR` when querying but I found a workaround 
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/performing-or-queries-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-for-javascript-with-rxjs-c361671b201e

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here: "Should I query my data in firebase or when I get the data back from firebase".  What exactly is the decision you have to make?  What are your concerns about that decision?

Comment: @DougStevenson that's very good question. I'm concerned that I will have to pay a lot and I'm concern on getting into handling the OR in a hackie way through firebase since there's not a native way to do it

Comment: As I said before, I don't understand what two choices you're trying to compare.

Comment: my choice is query my json with all my data on the client with the filteres selected or create a query with the filteres selected and bring the data from firebase based on the query @DougStevenson

Comment: If you can do it with no problems on the client at no cost, I'm not sure why you'd ever do it on a paid service.

Comment: @DougStevenson make sense. Thanks for your time!